# Webpack - HTML loader doens't scan all files

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-html-loader

I have implemented `html-loader` on my Webpack configuration file:

```js
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/i,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: ['html-loader'],
        },
    ]
}
```

When I try to run webpack dev-server with the following line in `index.js`

```js
import html from  `./app/components/auth/auth.html`;
```

it's return the following error:
[image]

I have tried to log all the files which are scanned and it seems that Webpack doesn't even check the entire `app` directory in my `src` folder:

```js
{
    test: (path) => {
        console.log(path)
        return /\.html$/i.test(path)
    },
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    use: ['html-loader'],
},
```

The only HTML file that was printed was `index.html`, which is located in the directory where `webpack` files are located.

### My directory:

[image]

Comment: Don’t use backticks in your import statements. Use single quotes instead.

Comment: @Terry lol. thanks. I actually done that because I have the following question: when Im using `import()` on runtime, to fetch HTML file, It returns me a module object. instead of a string. How can I fetch it as a string?